# Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: mysql

after the LAMP install, we are getting a error for mysql (unable to start the service)-

```
Aug 22 13:37:51 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Please help!

Comment: You misconfigured something. how should we know which of the billions of options you did wrong? Please add the output of `journalctl -u mysql.service` to the question. And add what LAMP you installed on which version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Edit post, give details: Ubuntu version for starters.

Comment: Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 mysql-systemd-start[94650]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 mysql-systemd-start[94650]: 2023-08-22T15:50:47.615919Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011272] [Server] SSL fips mode error: error:12800067:DSO support routines::could not load the shared libra>

Comment: Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 mysql-systemd-start[94650]: Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 mysql-systemd-start[94650]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Comment: Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 mysql-systemd-start[94750]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 mysql-systemd-start[94750]: 2023-08-22T15:50:47.847873Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011272] [Server] SSL fips mode error: error:12800067:DSO support routines::could not load the shared libra>

Comment: Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 mysql-systemd-start[94750]: Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 mysql-systemd-start[94750]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 22 15:50:47 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Comment: Aug 22 15:50:48 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 22 15:50:48 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 22 15:50:48 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 22 15:50:48 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 22 15:50:48 ip-24-0-0-35 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

Comment: The LAMP versions information is as follows-
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.13 (cli) (built: Jun 28 2023 14:01:49) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
AND
Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2023-05-03T20:02:51

mysql  Ver 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Comment: Do not use comment for things related to the question. Edit the question and add the information in a formatted way that makes it readable. Nobody will answer to this unreadable stuff.